# Esp32-c3 not able to connect to home router

Tags: wifi, esp32

I have bought 2 ESP32-C3 from [Waveshare](https://www.waveshare.com/esp32-c3-zero.htm) and tried many tutorials on how to connect them to the home router.

None of the code I used worked including the micropython example, Arduino example and not even the the ones from the ESP-IDF example folder.

I know the boards do work as all of the code examples from Arduino did work the moment I switched to the updated 3.0.0 alpha SDK. The problem with using that version is it is not compatible with the HomeSnap lib to connect to HomeKit, it only supports the ESP 2.14.0 lib.

I was hoping the official Espressif SDK would work at the bare minimum, but this is not working and leaving me puzzled as to why it is not working when I keep seeing YouTube tutorials that do and I did follow the installation process for the SDK.

The router I am trying to connect to is a dual-band 2.4/5g, run-of-the-mill cable isp [cable modem router](https://fizz.ca/en/wi-fi-technologies). And the code used is the one from the Espressif [GitHub](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/blob/5454d37d496a8c58542eb450467471404c606501/examples/wifi/getting_started/station/README.md)

Hope someone can find something in the logs below from the serial monitor attached the the IDF toolchain.

To see the max verbose logs, view these [files on github](https://github.com/nissaba/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/wifi/getting_started/station)

I also ran the scan example project to make certain my wifi was visible.

this is the one I am trying to connect to.

```
I (3067) scan: Total APs scanned = 11
I (3067) scan: SSID             FIZZ3211$
I (3067) scan: RSSI             -40
I (3067) scan: Authmode         WIFI_AUTH_WPA2_PSK
I (3067) scan: Pairwise Cipher  WIFI_CIPHER_TYPE_CCMP
I (3077) scan: Group Cipher     WIFI_CIPHER_TYPE_CCMP
I (3077) scan: Channel          6
```

Small Update: I tried the softAp example today and well I did not see the SSID on my iPhone, so I starting to wonder if the modules I bought from Waveshare are only able to receive wifi data and are unable to transmit. I do need to find a way to get the ISP router to log some info, that or buy a real router.

Comment: The ESP32-C3 only supports 2.4GHz wifi. Are you sure that you're trying to connect to an SSID on a 2.4GHz radio? Can you see the network you're trying to connect to when you run a wifi scanner on the ESP32-C3?

Comment: Yes the router is a dual band 2.4 / 5 . will add the info in the question.

Comment: Can you run a WiFi scan to check it actually sees your network? Also have you double checked the password and the authentication method?

Comment: I took the wifi login direct from my keychain/pasword store the ssid and paswd as been giga-checked ;) . As for scans, yes under Micropython and arduino I was able to scan the networks and my router was visible.

Comment: Do you by any chance have any form of MAC address filtering set up on the router which would prevent unknown devices from associating?

Comment: Also, can you set the log level to the maximum (verbose), check what changes in the logs if you use a wrong SSID or password, and log the reason code which should be returned?

Comment: @jcaron A) no MAC filtering. B) SSID or password are correct they have a 0.0% chance of being wrong as they are copy-pasted from the login credentials my computer is using. Also, I have tried this with my iPhone in AP mode and on all 3 routers at my workplace and my sys admin is puzzled that it can't connect. All routers are dual-band and both bands have the same name, I am now wondering if this is a problem for the API and if the current version is having a problem with that. It could explain why the 3.0.0 alpha library is working with the same credentials.

Comment: This is the run logs it is long so I setup the file in a fork, that I made for this on the Espresiff's repo https://github.com/nissaba/esp-idf/blob/master/examples/wifi/getting_started/station/run.log

Comment: The idea behind trying with different (voluntary wrong) SSID or password is to detect at which point the logs diverge and thus at which point if the complex connection flow the problem happens.

Comment: @jcaron Sorry, I didn't understand that you want me to try with the wrong SSID on purpose.  https://github.com/nissaba/esp-idf/tree/master/examples/wifi/getting_started/station I've added a varreid log files with ssid and bad password and with bad ssid.

Comment: See if you can go into your AP/router screens and turn on some logging there. That may give you some clues. Also, one more thing you can try is to turn off the dual banding in the router and only have 2.4, just to see if that works.

Comment: @kalyanswaroop I have decoupled my 2 bands, and still having the same problem. I saw on Reddit that I am not the only one having this problem. one of many other post like this https://www.reddit.com/r/esp32/comments/ncflor/problems_connecting_to_dual_mode_wifi/